# Firebase Hosting - OAuth Redirect

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to use a Firebase Hosted site with OAuth 2.0 for a third party API? I would like to use the [Quizlet API](https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization-code-flow). This requires an OAuth 2.0 redirection flow and a custom `state` parameter.

> State: A random string generated by you. You send us this, and we'll send it back to you, and you verify that we send back the same thing you sent.
>   You must send and verify this value in order to prevent CSRF attacks.

So for example:

`https://quizlet.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&scope=read&state=RANDOM_STRING`

This would take the user away from my Firebase Hosted page and then they would authenticate. Upon authentication, Quizlet would send me back to:

`REDIRECT_URL/?code=GENERATED_CODE&state=YOUR_STATE&expires_in=60`

Can I somehow catch these URL query parameters in my Firebase Hosted site or its Angular code?

Thanks!